# I'm having some confusion with loading a list of cities in to a dropdown list using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a simple weather app that asks for the country and then city which then shows the weather for the chosen city.

I've fallen at the first hurdle in that I can't get the cities to load. I'm trying to load the list of cities from a html file that contains a list of cities (I have four different html files which contain the cities in England/Scotland/Wales/Northern Ireland). I can select the country but the cities list doesn't load. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

This is the javascript (the only bit relevant to my current hurdle is the first 3 lines:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#countries').change(function() {
    $('#cities').load($(this).val() + '.html');
  });
  $('#cities').change(function() {
    var cityWeather = $(this).val();
    var city = $('#cities option:selected').text();
    var apiUrl = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&APPID=798c9a98f7fc15df80c7e21268f57941'
    cities = '' + cityWeather

    $.ajax({
      url: apiUrl,
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'json'
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
      }
      error: function() {

      }
    });
  });
});
```

This is the HTML for reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Weather App</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="apiweather.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Weather App</h1> 
    </header>
    <section>
        <select id = "countries">
            <option selected>Select a Country</option>
            <option value="england-cities">England</option>
            <option value="scotland-cities">Scotland</option>
            <option value="wales-cities">Wales</option>
            <option value="nireland-cities">Northern Ireland</option>
        </select>

        <select id = "cities">
            <option selected><< Please Select</option>
        </select>
        <div id = "info"><div>

    </section>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

and finally this is an example of a html list I'm dealing with:

```
<option>Select a City</option>
<option>Aberdeen</option>    
<option>Dundee</option>      
<option>Edinburgh</option> 
<option>Glasgow</option>     
<option>Inverness</option>
```

Any suggestions or resources are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're missing a `)` here: `$(this.val()` it should be `$(this).val()`

Comment: There's something missing here: `cities =' + cityWeather`

Comment: `&APPID={7` should be `&APPID=7`

Comment: `$('#city option:selected')` shouldn't that be `#cities`?

Comment: Are all these errors in the real code, or just copying errors? It's hard to help you if we don't know what the real problems are.

Comment: You're missing a `)` at the end of `$('#countries').change(`

Comment: You need to post the actual code without all these typos.

Comment: I've been making a lot of stupid errors like this. My text editor (atom) doesn't bring this issues up. I've fixed all the things mentioned (thanks for pointing them out!)

Comment: @Barmar surely I'm not missing a ```)``` after the ```$('#countries').change(``` because it says ```$('#countries').change(function() {```?

Comment: Line 4 should be `})`

Comment: Get a better IDE, I recommend PhpStorm.

Comment: Are you going to edit the question with the corrected code? And please indent it properly (I'm sure Atom can do that).

Comment: @barmar sorry I was trying to find a solution, i've edited the code. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't see a problem with the first 3 lines. Is there any error in the console?

Comment: I see issues in the `$("#cities").change()` function. You never use the city when calling the weather API.

Comment: @Barmar the only errors relate to the api bit, not the loading of the city list

Comment: Do you see the AJAX request for `england-cities.html` in the Network tab? Does it show that the expected HTML is being returned?

Comment: I don't know what happened but it works now! Thank you so much for your help!

One final question, the API is returning the temperature as like 278 which I guess must be in Kelvin, do you happen to know if there's a way to get that in celsius?

Comment: can you share "england-cities.htm" file